# How to pass shell script variable to python in databricks

Tags: python, shell, databricks

I am currently trying to use shell script variable in python.

Below is the code.

```
%sh
export MY_VAR="my_value"
echo $MY_VAR
```

```
%python
import os
my_var = os.environ.get("MY_VAR")
print(my_var)
```

Code screenshot

[image: Code screenshot]

I am getting the value in shell script but when i am trying to get the value using python `os.environ.get("MY_VAR")` i am getting as `None`

Could anyone help me to resolve the above issue.

Comment: You don't show how you invoke your Python program from within your Shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code in different languages run in separate contexts, you can't share environment variables between shell and Python, or variables between Python and Scala, etc.

You could use filesystem to pass data.

```
%sh
echo "my_value" >/tmp/foo

%python
from pathlib import Path
my_var = Path("/tmp/foo").read_text()
print(my_var)
```

Some other ideas in this article: https://medium.com/@robin.loche/how-to-work-with-multiple-languages-on-databricks-e22dea9f8c7

Comment: I agree with you